# Closing window on thread stop

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010

I have a question about threads and controls. I made a syncing modal dialog. There's three progressbars and couple of captions. If application is opened for a first time, then it will open syncing dialog and do the update thing. On dialog Show() method I create three different threads. Each thread controls data download, xml parsing and database inserting. And then shows progress on progressbar. All described, is working fine.

Now the problem - I want to close this dialog automatically when all items are downloaded, parsed and inserted to database. I tried to check if progressbar.position equals to progressbar.max and I tried check if threads are terminated.If I go with the progressbar way, dialog closes too early and one progressbar isn't totally ended. If I go with the thread checking way, then progressbars stop in the middle of process and that's all.

Maybe you have done it and tell the Delphi n00b, how is the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this simple thing, you can use the thread OnTerminate event (which runs in the context of the main thread) just to decrement a "thread count" variable initialized to 3 at thread creation moment.

When the thread count reaches 0, you can safely close the form.

```
begin
  //..thread creation, stuff
  FThreadCount := 3;
  DownloadThread.OnTerminate := DecThreadCount;
  ParseThread.OnTerminate := DecThreadCount;
  InsertThread.OnTerminate := DecThreadCount;
  //resume threads and other stuff
end;

procedure TForm1.DecThreadCount(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Dec(FThreadCount);
  if FThreadCount = 0 then
    Close;
end;
```

Comment: @Evilone: it is a TNotifyEvent.

Comment: Good answer, but IMO it would be more readable to call it "DecThreadCount".

Comment: @Mason, you're right... just my _poor_ english showing of. :D

Comment: This closes too early the form too, but the solution in nicer than mine was.

Comment: @evilone: what you mean by _too early_? is there any further processing after the three threads terminate? are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: I mean that if form closes then visually i see the progressbar not ending, but maybe it happens very fast.

Comment: @evilone: To archive the visual effect, take a look at [Mason Wheeler answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411408/closing-window-on-thread-stop/4411597#4411597), or you can even change the Close call to a CloseTimer.Enabled := True and just wait a few moments to let the progress bar reach the end.  Or maybe the progress bar max calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Windows Vista or Windows 7?  Microsoft changed the way progress bars work in Vista, so that instead of immediately jumping to the indicated position, it gradually slides towards it.  This means that your progress can actually be finished, but the bar won't indicate that for another second or so, so it looks like the dialog is closed before you're done, especially if the bar has a small number of progress steps.

It's kinda ugly, but you can work around this by using a helper function that does something like this:

```
procedure UpdateProgressBar(bar: TProgressBar);
begin
  bar.StepIt;
  bar.Max := bar.Max + 1;
  bar.Max := bar.Max - 1;
end;
```

This will ensure that it immediately jumps to the correct position.

EDIT: Details in [How do I make TProgressBar stop lagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061715/how-do-i-make-tprogressbar-stop-lagging)

Comment: +1 @Mason Now that you say this I've seen the effect you describe. Is this documented anywhere that you know of or did you work it out from experience?!

Comment: @David: I actually learned this from asking about it on StackOverflow.  Added a link in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get your threads to post a message back to the dialog when they complete. Once all three messages have been received you can close the dialog.

Comment: i'm new in delphi. How do you post those messages? Postmessage/Sendmessage? Can you show me an example?

Comment: @evilone In this case you could call either. To learn about basic win32 you should read Petzold's book.